# How would you get a webpage source from Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

On my website I have a text file with data on it (The site in question is hosted by GoDaddy, so I can't access the file locally).  This file is updated through PHP.  From the Unix/Linux/Mac bash I would like to get the contents of the text file so I can use it in scripts.  Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Make a http request somehow. There's a wget example below. I'm sure there are lots of other ways too.

Comment: Do you have `curl`? Or `wget`?

Answer (score 17):

`curl` is installed already on your Mac, so you don't need to install it. You will also find `curl` installed on pretty much any Linux distribution. That's probably your safest bet.

```
cd ~/Desktop
curl www.google.com >> google.txt
```

`wget` can be installed on your Mac easily with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). It will likely be installed already on most Linux distributions.

```
cd ~/Desktop
wget www.google.com
```

Answer (score 4):

Install [MacPorts](http://macports.org) and install `wget`:

```
$ sudo port install wget
```

And then:

```
$ wget http://godaddy.com/somewhere/somefile.txt
```

And the resulting text file will be `somefile.txt` (this can be changed using the `-O` option).

Comment: Or homebrew. Here's their slogan: _"Homebrew — MacPorts driving you to drink? Try Homebrew!"_

Comment: Perhaps - I've never found MacPorts anything but brilliant.  I do drink my fair share, but it's not because of MacPorts. That could be my slogan ;-)